# Rails 4 issue with mysql database tables after upgrading from Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, mysql2, ruby-2.0

I have upgraded recently my app to Rails 4 (from Rails 3.2).

But seems that the app doesn't find anymore some mysql tables, for example a table called `Accidents`.

In the app I find this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'gms.accidents' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `accidents`
```

Ok, it seems that the table doesn't exists anymore, then (seen that is in dev mode and there is no problem to reset the DB), I run in the terminal `rake db:schema:load`, but:

```
-- create_table("accidents", {:force=>true})
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Tablespace for table '`gms`.`accidents`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT.: CREATE TABLE `accidents`
[...]
```

What happened? The table doesn't exists but exists??
Why the app doesn't find anymore some tables?

Comment: 3 Suggestions: 1. Check your config/database.yml and make sure it has the right connection information. 2. Examine the data in a mysql tool or prompt and check things there  3. Tell us which tables DO work?

Comment: thanks @MichaelDurrant for the suggestions. In synthesis: 1. is ok; 2. with a mysql tool the table doesn't exists (don't know why); 3...; I have removed manually the database (with rake db:drop doesn't work...) and then re-create another one. Now seems that work, but it's strange what is happend.

Comment: ok then I'll post that as answer, I've done that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option (not a fix but may let you move forward).

If this is just a development or local database, drop the database manually and update the schema_migrations table and then rake:db migrate to recreate from scratch.

Comment: just a note: better than rake db:migrate is: 1. rake db:create, 2. rake db:schema:load (so it loads directly the "final" version of db and not all migrations)

Comment: Yes that works and can be a better option in many cases.  Note of caution: If people have put data updates as well as schema (yes I see this) there can be issues.